# Laravel File vs Storage facade

Tags: file, laravel, storage, facade

Is there any differences between `File` and [`Storage`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem) facades in laravel 5.2 ?
it seems they both use the same contract.i see no documentation for `File` in laravel documentation.
if they are different how may interact with each other?

Answer (score 16):

File is a quite simple wrapper for PHP functions such as file_exists() etc. Storage is "a powerful filesystem abstraction thanks to the wonderful Flysystem PHP package by Frank de Jonge". This can be used to act on local files (i.e `Storage::disk('local')->exists('path')`).

Prior to Laravel 5, Laravel had no Flysystem integration. At that time, the File facade was "the way" to interact with (local files). I would guess that the documentation for File is removed in order to make users use the Storage instead. The Filesystem does work though.

Comment: thanks.you mean there is no need to `File` facade at all?`Storage` will do all  jobs ? in documentation examples taylor has used `file_get_contents()` although he could use `File::get()` instead.maybe `File` is going to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The **File Facade** just contains some primitive methods that work only with absolute path or relative to your script:

- `\File::makeDirectory('/home/www/myProject/storage/app/uploads/14214');`
- `\File::copy('/home/www/myProject/storage/app/uploads/14214/test.json', '/home/www/myProject/storage/app/uploads/99999/test.json');`

---

The  **Storage Facade** contains a set of complex methods and is a wrapper for other 3rd party tools.

The first advantage is, you can use relative path to a folder:

- `Storage::makeDirectory('uploads/14214');`
- `Storage::copy('uploads/14214/test.json', 'uploads/99999/test.json');`

you may change the default folder `/storage/app` in `config/filesystems.php` or create other disks that you may call with `Storage::disk('specialxyz')->copy(...)`.

Also you can save `raw file contents` into a file like this:

- `Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents);`

And my favorite, its very easy to upload user files by

```
$path = Storage::putFile('avatars', $request->file('avatar'));
```

or

```
 $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

> By default, the store method will generate a unique ID to serve as the
>   file name. The file's extension will be determined by examining the
>   file's MIME type. The path to the file will be returned by the store
>   method so you can store the path, including the generated file name,
>   in your database.